# VS CShellManager not declared

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, mfc

I have downloaded an API to further develop it and this error appears: C2065 CShellManager not declared. I guess it might be declared in a library which is not included by default, but it should be in the zip I have downloaded. How can a look for the declaration of this class in order to know the file in which is declared and to include this library in the source code?

Comment: What API are you talking about? Are you developing MFC application?

Comment: Its the Interactive Brokers API. Yes, it is a MFC application.

Comment: did you try #include <afxshellmanager.h> ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `CShellManager` class is a part of MFC framework. It is defined in `afxshellmanager.h` header file.

This class was introduced in VS 2008 as part of so called **MFC Feature Pack**. 
Basically it is only required if your project uses `CMFCShellTreeCtrl` and such. If this is the case then you need to call `CWinAppEx::InitShellManager()` in `OnInitInstance()` of your app class to initialize the instance of the Shell Manager.